# Loading json data to div using jquery ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the given below code. I am trying to load data in a div using json call.

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "JSON"
    }, function(data){
        $('#99').append(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    return false;
}
```

It would be great if someone can put some light on `$.ajax, $.get, $.post and $.getJSON`

Comment: Firstly your code has some syntax errors. Secondly I assume that's a cross domain request, which you'll have SOP issues with. Lastly have you checked the [API](http://api.jquery.com) for those functions? It covers pretty much everything you can possibly do.

Comment: That's a cross-domain request, right? That won't work because browsers (deliberately) don't allow it. @RoryMcCrossan - what are the syntax errors?

Comment: I made a simple HTML page with a blank div with Id="99" and a button which calls this function. The above URL just returns a JSON which I am using for test. So you can say its a cross doamin request

Comment: @nnnnnn the success handler function (I presume) stuck in the middle of the parameters.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok, the success function was the problem I got it out and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing `$.get` and `$.ajax`

Use this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two",
    dataType: "json"
}).success(function(data){
    $('#data').append(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j3vsg/

Comment: You were passing success as an argument to the $.ajax function, instead i passed it to a chained method (.success). 
Check jQuery documentation to see how this function works.